# Querying local datastore in using ParseQueryAdapter gives 0 results even after successfully pinning

Tags: android, parse-platform, local-datastore, android-parsequeryadapter

**Background:**
I am working on a group messaging app for Android using parse.com as my backend.

**Working:**

1. I Have a ParseQueryAdapter which queries for ChatGroups from the local datastore using:

   ```
   public ChatGroupAdapter(final Context context) {
          super(context, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ChatGroup>() {
             public ParseQuery<ChatGroup> create() {
                 ParseQuery<ChatGroup> chatGroupQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery(ChatGroup.class);
                 chatGroupQuery.fromLocalDatastore();
                 Log.d(ChatGroup.class.getName(), "Constructor query: " +  
                 chatGroupQuery + " made");
                 //noinspection unchecked
                 return chatGroupQuery;
             }
      });
   }
   ```
2. The fragment that contains it listens to it by adding a `ParseQueryAdapter.OnQueryLoadListener`. If the `ParseQueryAdapter` cannot retrieve the `ChatGroup`s from the local datastore, it retrieves it from parse, pins it and then triggeres the `ParseQueryAdapter` to retry loading from the local datastore using: `.loadObjects();`. Here is a code snippet from my fragment:

   ```
   @Override
       public void onLoaded(List<ChatGroup> groups, Exception e) {
           l.d("onLoaded called");
           if (e != null) {
               e.printStackTrace();
               updateLocalDatastore();
           } else if (groups == null) {
               l.w("Received null group list.");
               updateLocalDatastore();
           } else if (groups.size() == 0) {
               l.w("Received group list of size zero.");
               updateLocalDatastore();
           } else {
               l.d("Chat groups loaded successfully");
           }
       }

   private void updateLocalDatastore() {
       final ParseQuery<ChatGroup> groupQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery(ChatGroup.class);
       groupQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ChatGroup>() {
           @Override
           public void done(final List<ChatGroup> chatGroupList, ParseException e) {
               if (e != null) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               } else {
                   if (chatGroupList != null) {
                       ParseObject.pinAllInBackground(chatGroupList, new SaveCallback() {
                           @Override
                           public void done(ParseException e) {
                               if (e != null) {
                                   e.printStackTrace();
                               } else {
                                   l.d("Successfully pinned: " + chatGroupList.size() +
                                           " groups to local datastore. Reloading adapter");
                                   groupAdapter.loadObjects();
                               }
                           }
                       });
                   } else {
                       l.e("Received null group list from cloud! " +
                               "Local datastore update failed!");
                   }
               }
           }
       });
   }
   ```

**Result:**
And here is a simplified log of the execution:

```
ChatFragment: onCreate
ChatFragment﹕ Initializing chat groups
ChatFragment﹕ Loading chat groups
ChatFragment: onStart
ChatFragment: onResume
ChatFragment﹕ onLoaded called
ChatFragment﹕ Received group list of size zero.
ChatFragment﹕ Successfully pinned: 3 groups to local datastore. Reloading adapter
ChatFragment﹕ Loading chat groups
ChatFragment﹕ onLoaded called
ChatFragment﹕ Received group list of size zero.
ChatFragment﹕ Successfully pinned: 3 groups to local datastore. Reloading adapter
ChatFragment﹕ Loading chat groups
ChatFragment﹕ onLoaded called
ChatFragment﹕ Received group list of size zero.
ChatFragment﹕ Successfully pinned: 3 groups to local datastore. Reloading adapter
ChatFragment﹕ Loading chat groups
ChatFragment﹕ onLoaded called
ChatFragment﹕ Received group list of size zero.
```

It seems obvious to me that the `ParseQueryAdapter` should retrieve a list of 0 the first time which triggers the `updateLocalDatastore()` which pulls 3 `ChatGroup`s from parse, pin them and then it should receive 3 from the local datastore. **However as seen in the log, it continues to find 0 `ChatGroup`s from the local datastore even after pinning them successfully!**

The project setup seems fine:

```
Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
Parse.initialize(this, AppProps.properties.appId, AppProps.properties.clientKey);
ParseUser.enableRevocableSessionInBackground();
Parse.setLogLevel(Parse.LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG);
ParseObject.registerSubclass(ChatGroup.class);
```

What am I doing wrong?! Am I missing something?

I implemented the exact same logic with `ParseUser` and it worked flawlessly! There seems to be something wrong with doing the same with `GroupChat`:

```
@ParseClassName("ChatGroup")
public class ChatGroup extends ParseObject {
```

Some say that it is a parse [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29473711/2110869) with relations in the local datastore. But I am not even using relations. Even a simple query from the local datastore doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I couldn't fix the problem, I discovered what the issue was. The issue is related to an underlying bug with the Parse SDK of Android: [ParseQuery gives 0 objects when querying from local datastore even after successfully pinning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30694602/parsequery-gives-0-objects-when-querying-from-local-datastore-even-after-success/30704769#30704769)