# ParseQuery gives 0 objects when querying from local datastore even after successfully pinning

Tags: android, parse-platform, offline, querying, pinning

I am using the Android SDK of parse.com and have arrived at a peculiar problem.

From a fragment's onCreate:

1. Fetch an object from the server.
2. Pin it.
3. Fetch an object from the local datastore.

Here is a snippet of the code from the onCreate:

```
ParseObject myChatGroup = ParseObject.createWithoutData("ChatGroup", "mOJGWRiLPC");
    myChatGroup.fetchInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject chatGroup1, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                l.d("Fetched chat group: " + chatGroup1 + " from server");
                chatGroup1.pinInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            l.d("Successfully pinned chat group");
                            ParseQuery<ParseObject> chatGroupParseQuery = new ParseQuery<>("ChatGroup");
                            chatGroupParseQuery.fromLocalDatastore()
                                    .findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
                                            if (e == null) {
                                                l.d("Found " + list.size() + " chat groups from local datastore");
                                            } else {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                        } else {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
});
```

Here is the log:

```
Fetched chat group: ChatGroup { objectId: mOJGWRiLPC, name: Admin } from server
Successfully pinned chat group
Found 0 chat groups from local datastore
```

But this doesn't make any sense! I just pinned an object so how can there be 0 objects in the local datastore. The code is so simple. **What am I doing wrong? Could it be a bug with the SDK?**
Any insight will be much appreciated I have been trying to find the issue for days now.

The Parse setup looks fine to me:

```
    ParseObject.registerSubclass(ChatGroup.class);
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
    Parse.initialize(this, AppProps.properties.appId,
            AppProps.properties.clientKey);
    ParseUser.enableRevocableSessionInBackground();
    Parse.setLogLevel(Parse.LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG);
```

Note:

- It works fine when trying the same logic with the ParseUser object. And even other classes of mine like my `Message` which leads me to suspect that something is wrong with my ChatGroup class.
- I have added two fields to my `ChatGroup` class on the parse.com data browser: name(String) and messages(Relation) with read and wrote access to a role called Admin.
- When browsing to the actual parse db (using root access) I find that the database table (`ParseObjects`) does contain the row that I pinned. But somehow parse shows 0 results on querying it!

Comment: Just a random shot, try replacing fromLocalDatastore() with fromPin(). Apologies if it doesnt make sense.

Comment: Haha! Thanks but I tried that same random shot.. it was the first thing I tried but no luck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. It seems to be more like a bug with the Android SDK of parse. I narrowed it down to an issue with retrieving pinned objects with special ACLs using the Android SDK.

Initially, the object had the ACL such that only the role 'Admin' (that I created) can read and write. The funny thing is that the user with which I was testing the pinning and querying was an 'Admin'! But, when I changed the ACL such that public can read but only Admin can write, the problem was resolved!

My theory was that *querying the local datastore behaves like a public query, no matter what role the user that is making the query has*! But if any other theory explaining this would be appreciated. Luckily, in my case I need public read access, but this bug can be a huge downfall for some who need to have read access restricting ACLs! Hopefully parse.com will fix this issue soon.
This is quite a big issue! I am surprised that I couldn't find a question regarding this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Parse doesn't seem to support ACLs on local datastore.  So the easiest way to get around this issue is to do ignoreACLs() on the query -- assuming you do have roles/acls setup correctly on the server side, so whatever you have pinned locally should be OK permission-wise already.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah so basically you have to set ACL for current user and pin it before you pin the chat group.

```
ParseACL acl = new ParseACL();
acl.setReadAccess(ParseUser.getCurrentUser(), true);
ParseUser.getCurrentUser().setACL(acl);
ParseUser.getCurrentUser().pinInBackground();
```

Comment: Could you explain the logic behind doing so? After I do that, can I then set `ParseRole` ACLs on the chat group or does it still not solve that issue?

Comment: I had this problem of retrieving ParseObjects from local database every time that I was offline (no wifi or mobile network), even that my objects are pinned in local database, so I guess this is a bug with parse sdk. I assume that you can set than ParseRole on chat group object.